# mpdf working in postman but not in chrome

Tags: php, angularjs, mpdf

i'm trying to generate and and download pdf using `mpdf`. its working fine in the postman but soon as i try in the chrome it doesn't work.

this is my angular rest req

```
 $http({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/services/generatePDF?uniqueID=INV0005',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'securityToken': '123',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
 }).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res)
 }, function(ress) {
    console.log(res)
 })
```

this is my php code

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');


$pdf= new mPDF(); 
$pdf->SetHTMLFooter('<span style="color:#a1a1a1;font-size:12px;padding-left:100px;"> powered by 12thdoor </span>');
$pdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$pdf->WriteHTML($body,2);
$pdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'D');
```

this is the error i'm getting

```
bc81
%PDF-1.4
%    
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595.280 841.890]
/TrimBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890]
/Resources 2 0 R
/Group << /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB >> 
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 1334>>
stream
x  Y n F g}
```

i already tried using `application/pdf` content type header in angularjs and still not working.thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to Download Binary Files with AngularJS

When downloading binary files, it is important to set the `responseType`:

```
$http({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/services/generatePDF?uniqueID=INV0005',
    //SET responseType
    responseType: 'blob',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'securityToken': '123',
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
    }
 }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
 }, function(response) {
    console.log(response.status);
 })
```

If the `responseType` is omitted the XHR API defaults to converting [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded text to [DOMString (UTF-16)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) which will corrupt PDF and image files.

For more information, see [MDN Web API Reference - XHR ResponseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType)

Comment: thanks bro.i create a new function to download blob file manually after the response. now its working fine. u saved me a lot of time. cheers